# Form Submit trigger creates 2 Trello Cards

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms, trello

I am using Google Forms to populate a Google Sheet, for which I have written a script, using google script, that creates a Trello card via e-mail each time someone fills out the form and submits.

It works--it creates a Trello card for me with all the information populated that I want--but it also creates a 2nd Trello card, one with only the headers populated (and some in the wrong place).

Desired (& working) card output:

[image: Working Trello Card]

Extra (unwanted) card:

[image: ExtraTrelloCard]

This is happening every time a form is submitted, and I only want the first card to be created with all the request information in Trello.

Any advice on what I've got wrong in my code to stop the extra e-mail from coming through?

Below is my script:

```
function onFormSubmit (e) {
  try {
    var TrelloEmail = "example@boards.trello.com";
    var RequestTitle = e.values[9];
    var ContactName = e.values[1];
    var ContactEmail = e.values[8];
    var ContactDepartment = e.values[2];
    var SudgDate = e.values[7];
    var RequestDescription = e.values[3];
    var BusniBenefits = e.values[4];
    var ExtraInfo = e.values[5];
    var ExistingReport = e.values[6];

    var Subject = RequestTitle

    var Message = 
      "**Submitted by: **" + ContactName +
      "\n\n" + "**Department: **" + ContactDepartment +
      "\n\n" + "**Requested Completion By: **" + SudgDate + "\n\n" +
        "---" +
      "\n\n" + "**Request Description:**" + "\n" + RequestDescription +
      "\n\n" + "**Business Benefits: **" + "\n" + BusniBenefits +
      "\n\n" + "**Extra Infomation: **" + ExtraInfo +
      "\n\n" + "**Existing Report: **" + ExistingReport;


    MailApp.sendEmail(TrelloEmail, RequestTitle , Message);
  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

[Execution of Trigger occurring twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiRFu.png)

*There is sometimes a delay between the Desired card and the unwanted card. Sometimes a couple of hours. I still haven't found a solution to this question*

Comment: Do you perchance have a form submit code for both the Form's Apps Script project, and the destination Sheet's Apps Script project?

Comment: @tehhowch how would I check that?

Comment: Check your G Suite Developer Hub and look at triggers associated with those projects. Open the associated container resource (form, sheet) and access the Script Editor, if any, then check for submit triggers. Also consider checking with other developers to see if they have triggers for an earlier script version.

Comment: @tehhowch There is only one trigger that I have set up. But when i go to executions, it is executing twice. I have edited the bottom of my post with the image showing this. Any ideas on what could be causing this?